# Issues with training mask R-CNN for detecting 400~500 small droplets

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am currently working on a project where I would have to detect 400~500 circular objects on a given image. The radius of the circular objects range from 2~3 pixels to 10 pixels on a 512 X 512 size image. To train the network, I annotated a single image with 450ish annotations. To see the feasibility of MaskRCNN, I trained the network using the single image for 50~100 epochs with different training parameters. Since my GPU is only 5GB memory, for now I have trained on a CPU.

I have tried adjusting the following parameters: increasing the IMAGE_MIN_DIM & IMAGE_MAX_DIM to 1024, reducing RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES, increasing DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES and MAX_GT_INSTANCES to 450, and more.

However, the rpn_bbox_loss and mrcnn_class_loss does not decrease, regardless of the parameters I try.

Therefore, my question is:

1. Is it a wrong approach to train over 50-100 epochs on a single image with 400ish annotations to see the feasibility? Would adding more training data resolve the problem?
2. If not, is it up to the parameter finetuning to maximize the performance?
3. Is mask-RCNN incapable of segmenting tiny objects (circles of radius <4 pixels)?

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. 3. No.

Comment: Could you add a little bit more explanation please? That would provide very much help :)